# 'NoneType' object is not callable : How to parse an XML url link using python?

Tags: python, xml, parsing

**I am trying to parse this XML link, but whenever I try to get root by using getroot() function It says 'NoneType' object is not callable. And I also want to know how can I iterate through this XML and print all the string tags inside the entry tag. **

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url='https://www.omicsdi.org/ws/dataset/pride/PXD002885?debug=false'   // this is the XML url you can refer to
print(url)

response =requests.get(url)   //getting some output as: b'{"database":"Pride","file_versions":[{"files":{"Mgf":["ftp://ftp.pride.ebi.ac.uk/pride/da...........


soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
print(soup)                //getting output as: <html><body><p>{"database":"Pride","file_versions":[{"files"................

myroot = soup.getroot()    // getting error: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

`b'{"database":"Pride"...` is JSON, not XML, so you don't need beautifulsoup.

```
response = requests.get(url) 
data = response.json()
print(data["database"])  # 'Pride'
for fv in data["file_versions"]:
    print(fv["files"])
```